# why is adapter.clear() clearing both adapter and arrayList

Tags: android

In this activity, i am fetching all contacts and showing in `listView` and there is a `EditText` to search the contact like, if i write "ni" then the `listView` will show all contact starting with "ni". to do so i am using `adapter.clear()` and `adapter.addAll(matchedContacts`, all contact start with "ni") for every key stroke. But here the problem is that every call of `adapter.clear()` is clearing the main list of contact that is `contactList` (where i have stored all contacts) and filling it with `matchedContacts`, beacause of that if i change `EditText` the `listView` is not populating with new contact.

Here is the code:

```
public class AddPerson2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addperson2);

        EditText searchContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contact_search);
        final ListView listView =  (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        final ArrayList<String[]> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}
                , null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        if (cursor != null){
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String[] contact = new String[2];
                    contact[0] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    contact[1] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            }
        }

        final ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, contactList);
        listView.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);

        searchContact.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String startingCharacter = s.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<String[]> matchedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String[] contact : contactList) {
                    if (contact[0].toLowerCase().startsWith(startingCharacter)){
                        matchedContacts.add(contact);
                    }
                }

                contactListAdapter.clear();
                contactListAdapter.addAll(matchedContacts);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.personSelectBackground));
                Log.wtf("showid", id+"");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ContactListAdapter` is an `ArrayAdapter`, then `clear()` is behaving as expected:

- It calls `clear()` on the underlying `ArrayList`, thereby emptying it
- It calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the attached `AdapterView`, to let it know about the changes in the data

Perhaps you want to be using filtering on the adapter, by calling `getFilter().filter()` on the adapter. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/ActionBar/SearchView) demonstrates this, though I use a `SearchView` instead of an `EditText`.

Comment: using getFilter().filter(startingCharacter) leaves listView blank.